# How to change onClick tracking for Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

On some of the websites I work on there is a facility to generate an online quote. If a visitor wants to generate a quote, they have to complete 4 steps, each with a "next" button at the bottom of the page. The URL does not change when moving on to the next step of the form so a virtual page view is sent each time a "next" button is clicked. This allowed me to set up a goal with funnel to see how visitors interact with the quote form.

This is what the piece of code I'm using currently looks like:

onClick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/Quote1']);"

I have now created a new Universal property in analytics where I'm going to set up and check my goals before upgrading the original property from the asynchronous version.

So, my question is, do I need to change this bit of code to work with Universal Analytics? Or will this work with both versions?

I'm a marketing guy and I know very little about coding so I'd really appreciate a response!

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to the old code to the new [Universal Analytics syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#virtual-pageviews), which should make a little more sense to you, marketing guy.

The updated code will look like this:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', '/Quote1');"
```

*I removed the javascript prefix from the onclick because it's redundant.

Comment: Did it work? If it did, could you check my question as the correct answer?

Comment: The developer has just updated this code for me. It now looks like: 

<a onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', '/Quote1');" class="proceed" id="proceed2" href="#"></a>

but I can't see the pageview in real time when in analytics. Normal pageviews are working fine. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: No idea. The syntax is correct, so it should be working. I'm wondering if they are using jQuery/Javascript to attach a click event. Any chance you can share the site?

Comment: The site is www.vanleasing.com. If you select a van on the homepage and click "find my van", you'll be taken to a page with a photo of the van. If you then click the "quote me" button you will be taken to the quote form. The "step 2" button at the bottom of this page is the one I am having difficulty with. 

Really appreciate you help!

Comment: First off, you're using Google Tag Manager, which has a different way of implementing a virtual pageview than traditional implementing Universal Analytics on the page. Here is a [blog post](http://www.swellpath.com/2013/09/google-analytics-virtual-pageviews-la-google-tag-manager/) on how you would setup vpv's for tag manager. Odds are, you already have a lot of this setup. You'll just need to make the necessary adjustments within GTM.

Comment: Thanks @Blexy, I don't want to keep bothering you but after your help it looks like I'm 99% there! I am now collecting data for the form in analytics, but I can see that the click listener is not firing when I click the "Step 2", "Step 3", "Quote Me" or "Back" buttons at the bottom of this form. Any ideas what could cause this? The click listener is working for everything else! Thank you